# Python Sqlite3 Database Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to run a program to put prices into the database but when I try to write to the database I get an error. I'm using Python3.4 and I have sqlite version 3.7.14.1

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('/../../stocks.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into apple values (?,?)",(price,time))
con.commit()

#error
cur.execute("insert into apple values (?,?)",(price,time))
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18589280/4099593

Comment: Path to db looks wrong. `/` as the first character of a path always means the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `con = sqlite3.connect('/../../stocks.db')`

with

```
con = sqlite3.connect('../../stocks.db')
```

or with the correct path to stocks.db

In `con = sqlite3.connect('/../../stocks.db')`, `/` as the first character of a path means the root directory, and from `/` the parent `..` is also the root directory `/`

So `/../../stocks.db` is `/stocks.db` which is probably not where the stocks.db actually is, if you meant a relative path.

When a db file does not exist, sqlite3 will still try to open it as a new database *if file permissions permit*.  However, in this case the user probably doesn't have permission to write to the root directory at `/stocks.db`